# Get world position of a pixel from texture2d/sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up an automatic system to be able to attach a sprite and it will gather all its colours and the world position of each sprite. A list/class of all the colours used has been set up but how would get the position of all these sprites?

I have already tried doing this mathematically like getting the complete size of the sprite and then working out the size of each pixel and then working out the position from that. But this seems flawed due to the position of the sprite possibly changing.

```
Sprite ColouredSpriteTexture = ColoredSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        Texture2D ColouredTexture = ColouredSpriteTexture.texture;
        float XsizeF = ColoredSprite.transform.localScale.x;
        int Xsize = (int)XsizeF;
        float YsizeF = ColoredSprite.transform.localScale.y;
        int Ysize = (int)YsizeF;
        List<Color> TempList = new List<Color>();

    //Could spawn pixels by getting x and y size and dividing them by 100 50/100 = 0.50f
    //if the tile has a color then spawn pixel if not 0.50 += 0.50
    //TODO test if this logic will work

    float PixelSize = XsizeF / 100;
    float currentPos = PixelSize;

    for (int x = 0; x < Xsize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Ysize; y++)
        {
            int listAmount = TempList.Count;
            Color ColoredTex = ColouredTexture.GetPixel(x, y);
            float TextureAlpha = ColoredTex.a;

            if (!TempList.Contains(ColoredTex) && TextureAlpha != 0)
            {
                TempList.Add(ColoredTex);
                ColorByNumber tempColor = new ColorByNumber();
                tempColor.Color = ColoredTex;
                tempColor.ColorNumber = listAmount;
                ColorOptions.Add(tempColor);

            }

            if(TextureAlpha == 1)
            {
                GameObject ColorPixel = Instantiate(PixelPrefab);
                ColorPixel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(XsizeF, YsizeF, 0);
                ColorPixel.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
                ColorPixel.name = "Pixel (" + x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString() + ")";
            }

        }
    }
```

All I would need is somehow each pixel returning its position so I can store this data and be able to spawn anything on top of this pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to test this math yet so there may be some mistakes in it:

Every graphical image in Unity has a PPU, this and the object scale are going to be a huge factor. For argument sake I am going to clearly define these for 1 object.

- Image dimensions : 128x128
- PPU: 64
- Scale:  1,1,1
- Object Bounds: would
  come from the renderer, which I am unsure if that bounds already
  takes in account the scale(Most likely) however in the case you
  cannot use that you can calculate the ObjectBoundsWidth or height
  just by  dividing the width or height of the texture by the PPU. 
  This should give you bounds of the texture in world space.

We are also going to make an assumption that we are only working on the X and Y axis and ignore the Z axis, if you want to use Z instead of Y then just make the necessary changes to be Z Scale and Z position and Z Bounds.

World position of a pixel located at 2,10.  Per the documentation the pixel coordinates start at the lower left this means 0,0 is the bottom left corner, and 2,10 is 2 pixels left and 10 pixels up.

EDIT:
So I plugged all of this into a google sheet and determined the previous algorithm I provided was wrong here is the correct one in a pseudo code format

```
// This function takes in either the x or y, and the width or height of 
// the bounds, then the x or y position of the object attached to.

// It also assumes the pivot is the center of the sprite.
float CalculateWorldPosOfPixelCoordinate(int coord, float boundsSize, float position, float scale)
{
    float PixelInWorldSpace = 1.0f / PPU;
    float startPos= position - (boundsSize* 0.5f * scale);

    return startPos + (PixelInWorldSpace * coord) * scale;
}
```

This is using objectBounds we determined ourselves that is why we are multiply by scale.

this would give use a world position of: -0.97, -0.84

The algorithm i believe is the same for Y, just replace the coord with the Y position, and the bounds with the height instead of the width.

Like I said this could be wrong as I havent had a chance to test it, this also does not account for rotation either.

Comment: This is awesome thank you, this algorithm has given an idea of how I could apply it to my code, I would vote this up but unfortunately, I do not use stack overflow enough to have the reputation.

Comment: I made a couple of edits, not sure if you saw the new version, but if this did answer your question you should be able to select it as the answer. @paddockson